# openssl's d2i_X509 complains with "wrong tag"

Tags: certificate, openssl, c, rsa

Tried to parse a DER key from a minecraft server auth protocol.
`openssl asn1parse -inform DER` correctly parses the key, but when I try to use `d2i_X509` function from within C to parse this data, I receive null, and the error stack looks like this:

```
140508081342272:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
140508081342272:error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_d2i_ex_primitive:nested asn1 error:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:713:
140508081342272:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:646:Field=serialNumber, Type=X509_CINF
140508081342272:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:646:Field=cert_info, Type=X509
```

This is how I call `d2i_X509`:

```c
X509 *key_struct = d2i_X509(NULL, byte_data, byte_data_length);
if(key_struct == NULL) {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
}
```

OpenSSL returns this:

```
openssl asn1parse -inform DER < out.bin
    0:d=0  hl=3 l= 159 cons: SEQUENCE          
    3:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
    5:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
   16:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
   18:d=1  hl=3 l= 141 prim: BIT STRING
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there isn't an X.509 structure (certificate) it's a `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` that is just defined in X.509 RFC that seems like an RSA public key. I'd suggest using another `openssl` function that is made to parse this structure `d2i_PUBKEY()` documented here: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/i2d_PUBKEY_bio.html